# Displaying & working with Core Data in NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, nstableview

**Background:** I've been teaching myself Swift, iOS and macOS for a few weeks and I've been trying to put together a 'Price Calculator' for macOS that grabs from a Database of paper and uses the selected properties to select a piece of paper. The user would be able to select from a list of properties such as: Size, Weight, Finish, Color, and Brand. From there it would calculate a price of the paper using general arithmetic.

*At first I thought about using a SQLite or a similar Database style program to populate my Calculator – but the User needs to be able to populate the Paper Database themselves. Thus, I've started working with Core Data.*

**Problem:** I have a tableView that's taking the Core Data and displaying the different paper's available *– or at least it should be doing that.* For testing, I've created a 'Add Paper' button that generates a random Paper and adds it to the Database. I know this is creating random random Paper because I'm able to display it in the Output. But I don't actually know if it's saving.

The problem I have is that when I try to refresh the table and display the Data to the tableView... it either Crashes due to Nil values or it does not add to the tableView.

I've come to the conclusion that I may be displaying the Data wrong to the table -OR- I'm not properly saving the Data -OR- I'm not fetching the Data correctly.

The resources online for iOS only helps so much as this is for Mac OS Any help in this would be appreciated. *My Code can be found below and Thank you in advance: NOTE: I'm using the boilerplate AppDelegate file from the CoreData.*

**Defined in ViewController:**

```
private var papers = [FlatPaper]()
private var appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
private let context = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

**The Add Random Paper button (for testing):**

```
@IBAction func addPaper(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let data = PaperData()
    let paper = FlatPaper(entity: FlatPaper.entity(), insertInto: context)
    paper.paperSize = data.paperSize
    paper.paperWeight = data.paperWeight
    paper.paperBrand = data.paperBrand
    paper.paperColor = data.paperColor
    paper.paperFinish = data.paperFinish
    paper.paperPrice = data.paperPrice
    appDelegate.saveAction(paper)
    papers.append(paper)
    print("Add Paper Button Pressed. \(paper)")
    refresh()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Extensions NSTableDelegate and NSTableDataSource:**

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    // Mark: - Specifying how many rows
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return papers.count
        }

    // Mark: - Populating the Columns and Rows with Data
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        let paperSpecs = papers[row]
        
        if tableColumn!.title == "Paper Size" {
            return paperSpecs.paperSize
        } else if tableColumn!.title == "Paper Weight" {
            return paperSpecs.paperWeight
        } else if tableColumn!.title == "Paper Brand" {
            return paperSpecs.paperBrand
        } else if tableColumn!.title == "Paper Color" {
            return paperSpecs.paperColor
        } else if tableColumn!.title == "Paper Finish" {
            return paperSpecs.paperFinish
        } else {
            return paperSpecs.paperPrice
        }
    }

    // Mark: - Refresh Method for reloading all of the data
    private func refresh() {
        do {
            papers = try context.fetch(FlatPaper.fetchRequest())
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), USER INFO: \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Online resources for macOS: [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview). At the bottom is a link to the Table View Programming Guide for Mac.

Comment: Implementing `objectValueFor` indicates that you are using Cocoa Bindings. I guess the bindings are missing or aren't correct. And make the changes suggested by Joakim. He's right. Not related but in the `addPaper` method don't call `refesh` after having added the item to the data source array and having saved the context. Create an `IndexSet` from the last index and call `insertRows(at:withAnimation:)` to insert the table row with an animation.

Comment: Thanks for both of these! I'll have to visit that Table View Programming Guide resource. Also, good to know that objectValueFor is used for Cocoa bindings. I tried using that previously and I guess I never switched it back. It seems that I need to get a better grasp on Swift in general before proceeding with Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

In `tableview:objectValueFor` you should get your paper specs object from your array using the row argument instead of creating a new (empty) instance.

```
let paperSpecs = papers[row]
```

You might also want to look into [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller), it’s really helpful when working with Core data and table views.

Comment: I've changed this line but the tableView still does not update. This leads me to believe that it's how i'm presenting the Data in the table. I'm going to look into that tonight / tomorrow and possible try the NSFetchedResults Controller again. Hopefully I have better luck with it this time.